# Lambda timeout value not changing after timeout key added to Chalice config.json

Tags: python, chalice

I want my AWS Lambda function to run for longer than the default 60 seconds so have added the timeout key to `config.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "app_name": "mychaliceapp",
  "stages": {
    "dev": {
      "api_gateway_stage": "api",
      "lambda_functions": {
        "mylambdafunction": {
          "lambda_timeout": 120
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no error when running the `chalice deploy` command but the timeout had not changed:

[image]

How can I add the timeout value correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/1113) issue on Github it works if I keep timeout in the scope of stages directly and not in functions.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "app_name": "mychaliceapp",
  "stages": {
    "dev": {
      "api_gateway_stage": "api",
      "lambda_timeout": 120
    }
  }
}
```